# WMI Win32_process.create spawning processes in the background

Tags: python, wmi

I'm building a testing harness which is supposed to spawn a process on a remote machine, monitor it, and exit the process and report the data back to the host.  I've been using the WMI package for python, but I've run into an issue where the .exe I'm creating is getting spawned as a background process and obviously isn't running because it isn't using any resources.  Here's how I create the connection:

```
def __init__(self, ip, username, password):
    self.ip = ip
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

    try:
        print("Connecting to %s..." %self.ip)
        self.connection = WMI(ip, user = username, password = password)
        print("Connection established")
    except x_wmi:
        print("Problem connecting. Your username and password for " + getfqdn(ip) + " are incorrect.")
```

And here's creating the process:

```
def startBlueEnduranceTest(self):
    exe = "view.exe"
    if self.connection != None:
        print("Starting Blue on %s" %self.ip)
        cmdLine = self.exeLocation + '\\' + exe + " -enduranceTest=1337"
        self.processID, return_value = self.connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine = cmdLine)
        if return_value == 0:
            print("Started successfully. Running Endurance Test.")
        else:
            print("Failed to start up. Something must be wrong.")
    else:
        print("Connection to %s has not been established.  Could not start process." %self.ip)
```

Any help for creating the process properly (in the foreground) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define [`ProcessStartupInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388)

Comment: Does this help http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#run-notepad-wait-until-it-s-closed-and-then-show-its-text

Comment: @JosefZ I have tried startup information defined like this: `startup = c.Win32_ProcessStartup.new (ShowWindow=1)` and it is still not working properly.